# Portable soft fast C IDE

Tags: c, ide, portability

I haven't Note-book, but sometimes I must change my computer for University's ones. University's computers are braking, I haven't admin's access.
There are MS VS 2008 but it work so slow, that I can't program at all.
I use MS VS 2010 at home. And because of there's not project's compatibility, I think to use portable and soft compiler.

I program on C, and C alone for windows(win32). 
What IDE do you advise me to use?(starts from my flash and work fast on old hardware).

thank you.

Comment: Soft! *poke poke poke*. I suggest notepad++. I'm not sure where to find a portable c++ compiler though.

Answer (score 1):

You can carry [code::blocks](http://codeblocks.org) around portably following the directions [in their FAQ](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ#Q%3a_How_do_I_make_Code%3a%3aBlocks_portable.3F).

edit: There is also a pre-build [portable DevCPP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/devcpp-portable/files/), though it is several years old.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about carrying around your development environment on a USB pen drive or CD that you can boot any machine with?  Many people do this with Linux.  Checkout this link [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/).  You can carry your editor, C compiler, and code on a single USB pen drive and take it anywhere.  Most of the big linux distros have the capability to boot off of USB sticks.  I know you said Windows and Visual Studio but if "light weight" is your concern Linux/gedit/gcc will work best.